# I accepted 2 job offers to start same day but now I have a 3rd offer with another employer!

Tags: new-hires

I'm supposed to start both job offers this Monday. I made of mistake of jumping the gun in accepting one job after another not thinking I would be this lucky. Now I have a 3rd employer I just interviewed with yesterday and it looks like 99 % I will be also offered the job, however it takes 3 weeks for background and drug test. I don't want to end up losing out and have zero as I am unemployed now. I live in the United States. I went to do a drug test for one of the two employers where I am supposed to show up Monday at 8am. Honestly, I am looking forward to the 3rd company since it is a very large well known company with great benefits. What should I do to delay this since today is Friday.

Comment: see also: [Employment etiquette: should I apply for job B with a company, whilst waiting to start work for them on job A?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/employment-etiquette-should-i-apply-for-job-b-with-a-company-whilst-waiting-to) and [How to deal with rescinding acceptance of job offer at company B when company A countered?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36242/how-to-deal-with-rescinding-acceptance-of-job-offer-at-company-b-when-company-a)

Comment: Where are you located? Are you in an at-will employment state in the USA?

Comment: Yes, at will state. The reason I accepted both jobs not knowing both would work out. One was due to salary and the other was due to training schedule conflict.

Comment: Update:Company A and C did not work out. Company B worked on my hiring paperwork pretty fast and I start Monday. I was hoping for company C to offer me the job but it worked out for the best since I do have a friend that works at my new employer and for ethical reasons, I want to have a credible reputation. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you need to start Monday since you need money, and there is no guarantee of a job yet. However, if you do end up getting the job with the bigger company, just leave your new job and go there.

There are a couple things that will happen if you do this that you should be aware of:

1. You will burn bridges with the company you start with on Monday, for sure. It won't be a very comfortable conversation. You may not care about this, which is fine. However, if you were referred to that company by a friend that works there, for example, his reputation at the company will suffer.
2. Please read your employment contract with the company you start with on Monday, just to make sure the above is allowed.

After that, all is fair game assuming you live in an at-will employment state in the USA.